# formtastic approach has_and_belongs_to_many for huge table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic, has-and-belongs-to-many

What is the best why to implement has_and_belongs_to_many in formtastic giving that the table is so huge.

details:
I have 2 big tables
   1-people which has 100's of rows
   2-families

I am creating form for new family which has family members field. it makes no sense to have checkboxs for these large amount of people.

do you have any suggestion? (ready to use solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If relying on javascript does not bother you I suggest a setup with a multiple_select input and the 'chosen' library:  https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen  (talking about ready to use:) )
Good luck. Another way to do it is to create your own 'auto-suggest' feature and do the wiring (ajax calls; json rendering; etc.. yourself.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I am in love with "chosen" now ;)